# Getting the following error ' unauthorized: authentication required ' when i try to pull an image in docker

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-image, docker-cli

After installing the docker desktop on windows 10 i tried to pull the node image using the following command docker pull node, and that's what i get:

C:\Users\vPro>docker pull node

```
Using default tag: latest

latest: Pulling from library/node

d52e4f012db1: Downloading [============>]   12.1MB/49.55MB

7dd206bea61f: Downloading

2320f9be4a9c: Downloading [=================>]  22.54MB/64.11MB

6e5565e0ba8d: Downloading

5f1526a28cf9: Waiting

b9c7405b482f: Waiting

9db0bc99587b: Waiting

8e1c8c1907a5: Waiting

unauthorized: authentication required
```

Please note that I have executed the command docker login and successfully logged into my account.